# Rails Best practice Controller or Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to refactor my code according Rails Best Practice. Now I'm face with a problem where I have two instance variable at controller and I can't move them to the model. Here we are:

feedbacks_controller.rb

```
def get_feedback
  ...
  @employee = Employee.find_by(:name)
  if @employee.blank?
     ...
  else
    @client_feedback = Feedback.new(:screen_name => @screen_name, :feedback => @feedback)
    @client_feedback.employee_id = @employee.id
    @client_feedback.client_id   = @employee.client_id
    @client_feedback.location_id = @employee.location_id
    @client_feedback.save
```

According to [Rails Best practice Move Model Logic into the Model](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2010/07/21/move-model-logic-into-the-model/) all assignments inside the else need move to the model, my doubt is how I will start the `@employee` instance variable inside of model?

Comment: You won't, you'll pass in the instance. Though I might create a factory/utility method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a relation between Employee and Feedback you can do something like this

if you have has_one relation

```
@client_feedback = @employee.feedbacks.new(screen_name: @screen_name, feedback: @feedback)
@client_feedkback.save
```

if you have has_many relation

```
@employee.feedbacks << Feedbacks.new(screen_name: @screen_name, feedback: @feedback)
@employee.save
```

About the others fields (client and location ids) seems that you have reduntant data. Try to keep that data in a single place.

**ADDED**

In your model you have client_id and location_id, if you really need them on Feedback model you can do something like

```
@employee.feedback = Feedback.new(screen_name: @screen_name, feedback: @feedback, client_id : @employee.client_id, location_id:@employee.location_id )
@employee.save
```

Comment: I got it, so inside on Feedback model how do you suggest to set the attributes like this?   `self.employee_id = @employee_id`

Comment: employee_id you doesnt need because rails will save it by the relation, and all others fields can be sent on the new method (you don't need to do in a separated lines).